# Excel VBA to insert a page break before the row if the last 3 characters of the column are ":01"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a total novice with VBA. The title describes what I'm looking to do. I need a script to sarch a column (in my case, Column A) and if the last 3 characters are ":01" I need a horizontal page break inserted above it. Bonus points if you can make it skip the FIRST instance of ":01" and only insert page breaks on every subsequent appearance of ":01 in the column after that.

I've been accomplshing what I need with a very clunky process, where I insert a row before Row A, then paste this formula into every cell in the column: =IF(RIGHT(B3, 3) = ":01", 1,"")

Then I'll select Special, choose only numbers, and then run this VBA:

```
Sub AddPgBrk()
    For Each Cell In Selection
        ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add _
            Before:=Cell
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Then I delete Column A. It DOES work but I'd love to do it all in one step with a single VBA.

```
I tried this, and it doesn't give me any errors, but it also doesn't do anything:
```

Sub AddPgBrk()

```
Last = Cells(Columns.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Column
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
If (Right(Cells(i, "A"), 3)) = ":01" Then
        ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add _
        Before:=Cell
End If
Next i
```

End Sub

```
Appreciate the look and assistance. Thanks everyone!
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed a couple of things in your original code, noted below, and added a counter to avoid the first instance.

```
Sub AddPgBrk()

Dim Last As Long, i As Long, n As Long, j As Long

Last = Cells(Columns.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
n = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(1), "*:01")

For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Right(Cells(i, "A"), 3)) = ":01" Then
        j = j + 1
        If j < n Then
            ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add before:=Cells(i, "A")
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked EXACTLY as I needed it to. Thank you so much. Could you - or anyone - explain what the first line starting with Dim means?

Comment: I forgot to mention that. It's good practice to declare variables, e.g. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables

Answer (score 0):

### Add Manual Page Breaks

```vb
Sub AddPageBreaks()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    ' Remove only all manual horizontal page breaks.
    ws.Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone ' also 'ws.Rows' or 'ws.Columns'
    ' Remove all manual page breaks (horizontal and vertical).
    'ws.ResetAllPageBreaks
    ' But how to remove only all manual vertical page breaks?
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim pbCount As Long
    Dim FirstFound As Boolean
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        If Right(CStr(cell.Value), 3) = ":01" Then
            If FirstFound Then
                ws.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=cell
                'cell.EntireRow.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual ' much slower
                pbCount = pbCount + 1
            Else ' skip the first
                FirstFound = True
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    MsgBox "Manual horizontal page breaks added: " & pbCount & vbLf _
        & "Total horizontal page breaks: " & ws.HPageBreaks.Count, vbInformation
    
    'ws.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "Test.pdf", , True, False, , , True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This also worked perfectly, and also stopped the Hbreak at the last column. I'll have to study this one and break it all down to understand the coding. THANK YOU!

Comment: If I wanted to go a step further and add a bottom border at each page break, what lines of code would need to be added? I tried this but get a mismatch error:


Sub AddBottomBrder ()

 For Each pgbr In HPageBreaks
    
        With pgbr.Location.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With

    Next